# Foreign Tax Credit for US Citizens: Levied/Accrued?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, germany

I am a US citizen living long-term in Germany, paid by a German employer.

My taxes were deducted normally throughout the year from my paychecks, and sum to `A`. It turns out I overpaid a bit, by amount `B` which will get refunded in the end-of-year German tax form.

Also, I studied in Germany and my tuition will receive a tax rebate in large amount `C`.

So when I fill out my US tax form, and I take the foreign tax credit, what can I deduct as taxes levied/accrued in the foreign country? `A`? Or `A - B - C`?

Comment: If this is for last year's taxes, have you already filed the German tax return? Is this tuition tax rebate calculated on your German tax return?

Answer (score 1):

You deduct (or rather, take credit for on form 1116) `A-B-C`, and you need to have your German tax return ready by the time you prepare your US return. The deadline for US taxpayers abroad [is extended to June](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/us-citizens-and-resident-aliens-abroad) (from the regular April deadline) by default specifically because of the need to be able to calculate your local tax liability first. You can also receive an automatic extension till October by filing the [form 4898](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-4868).

Don't forget your FBAR (form 114).